# Dynamic regex against process.Path in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to identify processes that are running from a specific parent dir path build at run-time.

I try unsuccessfully:

```
$INSTALL_PATH=$ENV:PROGRAMFILES + "\my-ag\products" + $PVER
$ESCAPE_PATH=[regex]::escape("^" + $INSTALL_PATH + ".*")

$REGEX_PATH=[regex]$ESCAPE_PATH

if ( test-path $INSTALL_PATH) {
    get-process java | foreach{
        $pName = $_

        if ( $pName.Path -match $ESCAPE_PATH ) {
            # No printed, however there are 2 process running.
            write-output $pName.Path
        }

        if ( $REGEX_PATH.Match($pName.Path) ) {
            # prints all process even not from $INSTALL_PATH.
            write-output $pName.Path
        }
    }
}
exit 0
```

How to call/use properly the regex module to match the path?

Thanks !

Comment: For me it's not so clear. You should give examples of path you want to print and path you don't want to print.

Comment: The code prints two lines:  

    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe` and  
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\my-ag\products5.0\thirdparty\java\bin\java.exe`  

I want to only print the last one. There might be other programs running from `C:\Program Files (x86)\my-ag\products5.0\` which I want to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not use [regex] module I tried to use first, however helps me to match processes running under the INSTALL_PATH:

```
$INSTALL_PATH=$ENV:PROGRAMFILES + "\my-ag\products" + $PVER
function remove_prev_installation {
    if ( test-path $INSTALL_PATH) {
        get-process | foreach{
            $pName = $_
            write-output ("Path ..: " + $pName.Path)
            if ( $pName.Path -like ( $INSTALL_PATH + '*') ) {
                write-output ( "Will kill .. " + $pName.Path )
                # $pName.id | get-member
                Stop-Process $pName.id #-WhatIf
                $KILLED_P = 1
            }
        }
        if ($KILLED_P) {
            Start-Sleep -s 3 
            Remove-Item  -Force -Recurse $INSTALL_PATH
        }
    }
}
remove_prev_installation
```

Not sure if in this case it is really needed to wait 3 seconds before removing the files, however there had been other cases were the file handles were not release right away, and waiting a couple seconds solved the problem.

cheers!